# Is there a way to set the "--rm" option for a docker container deployed in a GCP compute instance?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm admittedly very new to Docker so this might be a dumb question but here it goes.

I have a Python ETL script that I've packaged in a Docker container essentially following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@jankrynauw/running-a-python-script-using-docker-pycharm-google-cloud-platform-2bc7ba999916), then using cloud functions and cloud scheduler, I have the instance turn start every hour, run the sync and then shut down the instance.

I've run into an issue though where after this process has been running for a while the VM runs out of hard drive space. The script doesn't require any storage or persistence of state - it pulls any state data from external systems and only uses temporary files which are supposed to be deleted when the machine shuts down.

This has caused particular problems where updates I make to the script stop working because the machine doesn't have the space to download the latest version of the container.

I'm guessing it's either logs or perhaps files created automatically to try to persist the state - either within the Docker container or on the VM.

I'm wondering whether if I could get the VM to run the instance with the "--rm" flag so that the image was removed when it was finished this could solve this problem. This would theoretically guarantee that I'm always starting with the most recent image.

The trouble is, I can't for the life of my find a way to configure the "rm" option within the instance settings and the [documentation for container options](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#overriding_the_default_command_to_execute_on_container_startup) only covers passing arguments to the container ENTRYPOINT and not the docker run options `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

I feel like I'm either missing something obvious or it's not designed to be used this way. Is this something that can be configured in the Dockerfile or is there a different way I have to set up the VM in the first place?

Basically I just want the docker image to be pulled fresh and run each time and not leave any remnants on the VM that will slowly run out of space.

*Also, I know Cloud Run might work in some similar situations but I need the script to be able to run for as long as it needs to (particularly at the start when it's backfilling data) and so the 15 minute cap on runtime would be a problem.*

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you starting and stopping the Compute Engine instance?

Comment: It starts and stops once an hour automatically. The problem is that after cumulative runs the hard drive is running out of space, despite the script only using temporary files. I'm concerned that docker is storing files in an attempt to persist state that I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

*Note*: I'm posting this as an answer as I need more space than a comment.  If anyone feels it is not a good answer and wants it deleted, I will be delighted to do such.

Recapping the story, we have a Compute Engine configured to start a Docker Container.  The Compute Engine runs the container and then we stop it.  An hour later we restart it, let it run and then we stop it again.  This continues on into the future.  What we seem to find is that the disk associated with the Compute Engine fills up and we end up breaking.  The thinking is that the container contained within the Compute Engine is created at first launch of the Compute Engine and then each time it is restarted, it is being "re-used" as opposed to a brand new container instance being created.  This means that resources consumed by the container from one run to the next (eg disk storage) continues to grow.

What we would like to happen is that when the Compute Engine starts, it will *always* create a brand new instance of the container with no history / resource usage of the past.  This means that we won't consume resources over time.

One way to achieve this outside of GCP would be to start the container through Docker with the "--rm" flag.  This means that when the container ends, it will be auto-deleted and hence there will be no previous container to start the next time the Compute Engine starts.  Again ... this is a recap.

If we dig through how GCP Compute Engines work as they relate to containers, we come across a package called "Konlet" ([Konlet](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/konlet)).  This is the package responsible for loading the container in the Compute engine.  This appears to be itself a Docker container application written in Go.  It appears to read the metadata associated with the Compute Engine and based on that, performs API calls to Docker to launch the target container.  The first thing to see from this is that the launch of the target Docker container does not appear to be executed through simple `docker` command line.  This then implies that we can't "simply" edit a script.

Konlet is open source so in principle, we could study it in detail and see if there are special flags associated with it to achieve the equivalent of `--rm`.  However, my immediate recommendation is to post an issue at the Konlet GitHub site and ask the author whether there is a `--rm` equivalent option for Konlet and, if not, could one be added (and if not, what is the higher level thinking).

In the meantime, let me offer you an alternative to your story.  If I am hearing you correctly, every hour you fire a job to start a compute engine, do work and then shutdown the compute engine.  This compute engine hosts your "leaky" docker container.  What if instead of starting/stopping your compute engine you created/destroyed your compute engine?  While the creation/destruction steps may take a little longer to run, given that you are running this once an hour, a minute or two delay might not be egregious.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you! I didn’t know about Konlet, I'll check that out. I was actually already thinking of your proposed solution originally as it would reduce costs while the machine was dormant.In reality the costs are so low that it wasn’t worth it but it’s something I might need to look into now. Time to spin up a new instance may be an issue if I want to run it more frequently. It also might make sense to use Cloud Run for more frequent updates but I also need to be able to use a static external IP which CR doesn't have yet.

I'll update if I find out more about Konlet

Comment: So this is interesting, it looks like Konlet might be running [--rm by default](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/konlet/blob/master/scripts/konlet-startup) and looking at my logs now I can see that it says `Removing a container created by a previous run of Konlet` - so I guess it must be running out of space some other way. Maybe logs or something like that. Will need to investigate further.

Comment: @ChrisGoddard - Make sure that you realize that "Konlet" is itself a docker container.  In the link you posted above, you are pointing to the code that starts Konlet.  Putting it another way, Konlet (the container) is being started with "--rm" and that says nothing about the container (your container) that Konlet is starting.  (As always, I reserve the right to be completely wrong :-)